# How to convert LSB extracted data to text or binary to text

Tags: c, text, binary, char

UPDATE***********************
For reference I included the program I made for opening a PPM image -  embedding a message into the image and then saving out a new image with the embedded text.  With the function below I'm hoping to extra that message, (hidden in the LSB) and then converting it to text to display it.  Thanks for the replies so far - I'm going to start testing them out and see if anything works.

---

I'm trying to write a function that extracts the LSB of an unsigned char value -  puts them bits together to form an extracted message.  I have the length of how many LSBs I need to extract from the file, but I'm having trouble with how to convert this into a message.

At first I extracted the first 8 bits into an int array - giving me something such as 00110000. Now I have an INT array with that value, and I need to convert it to a single char for the letter representation.  However, I think I should be taking in all of the LSBs into an array that is messageLength * 7 and somehow converting that int array into the text.  It would be giving me the binary represenation of the text before converting.  Maybe theirs a way to convert a long string of 1's and 0's to text?

```
unsigned char * extBits(PPMImage *img, int messageLen, unsigned char * decMsg)
{
    //int count = 2;
    int embCount = 0;
    int deM = messageLen * 7;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char byte;
//  int mask;
//  unsigned char update;
//  unsigned char flipOne = 0x01;  //0x01
//  unsigned char flipZero = 0xFE;  //0x00
    unsigned char dMsg[deM];
    int byteArray[7];
    int takeByte = 0;
    unsigned char *extMsg;
    char c;

    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        if(takeByte == 8)
        {
            //first letter extracted

            takeByte = 0;               
        }
        //byte = msgOne[j];
    //  byte = img->pixel[j];
        //encMsg[j] = byte;
        byte = img->pixel[j];
        //printf("byte: %c\n", byte); 
    //  printf("byte: %x\n", byte); 
        byte &= 1;
        //printf("byte after: %x\n", byte); 
        dMsg[j] = byte; 
        byteArray[j] = byte;
        data[j] = byteArray[j];
        printf("dMsg:%x ", dMsg[j]);        
    //  printf("pixel:%c \n", img->pixel[j]);       
        embCount++; 
        takeByte++;
    }
/*  
    for(int r=0;r<7;r++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", byteArray[r]);
    }   
    printf("count: %d", embCount);
    printf("%s ", dMsg);
*/
    return decMsg = dMsg;
}
```

embedding program*******

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
    execute as ./emb -i <img2embed> -i <text file> -o <embedIMG>

*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct {
    int x, y;
    unsigned char *pixel;
} PPMImage;

#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR 255

static PPMImage *readPPM(const char *filename)
{
    FILE * fp;
    PPMImage *img;
        int rgb_comp_color;
    int size = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "a+");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char *buff;
    unsigned char stuff[16];
    int c;
    int x,y;
    buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*size +1);
    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(unsigned char)*size+1);

        fgets(stuff, sizeof(stuff), fp);

    if (stuff[0] != 'P' || stuff[1] != '3') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image format (must be 'P3')\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    //alloc memory form image
    img = (PPMImage*)malloc(sizeof(PPMImage));
    if (!img) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = getc(fp);
    while (c == '#') {
        while (getc(fp) != '\n') ;
        c = getc(fp);
    }

    ungetc(c, fp);

    if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &img->x, &img->y) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image size (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &rgb_comp_color) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid rgb component (error loading '%s')\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (rgb_comp_color!= RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not have 8-bits components\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    //printf("x: %d y: %d\n", img->x, img->y);

    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer,0,1024);  
    fgets(buffer,1024,fp);

    fread(buff, 1, size, fp);   

    img->pixel = buff;
/*  
    for(int h = 0; h < 20; h++)
    {
        printf("%c", buff2[h]);

    }


    printf("%s", buff2);
*/
    fclose(fp);

    return img;

} 

void writePPM(const char *filename, unsigned char * img, int x, int y)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //open file for output
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    //write the header file
    //image format
    fprintf(fp, "P3\n");

    //comments
   // fprintf(fp, "# Created by %s\n",CREATOR);

    //image size
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n",x,y);

    // rgb component depth
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n",RGB_COMPONENT_COLOR);

    // pixel pixel
    fwrite(img,1, strlen(img), fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

//unsigned char * embBits(PPMImage *img, int messageLen, unsigned char*msgOne, unsigned char *encMsg)
int embBits(PPMImage *img, int messageLen, unsigned char*msgOne, int embLen)
{
    //int count = 2;
    int embCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char *eMsg;    
    unsigned char byte;
    int mask;
    unsigned char update;
    unsigned char flipOne = 0x01;  //0x01
    unsigned char flipZero = 0xFE;  //0x00

    for(int j = 0; j < messageLen; j++)
    {
        byte = msgOne[j];
        //encMsg[j] = byte;

        for(int k=7; 0 < k; k--)
        {
            update = byte;  

            update = update & (1<<k);
            //printf("pixel:%c\n", img->pixel[count]);      
            //printf("pixel+1:%c\n", img->pixel[count+1]);      
        //  printf("pixel+2:%c\n", img->pixel[count+2]);        
            if(update == 0)
            {
                // if i see 1   |=
                // if i see a 0 &=
                //img->pixel[count] = img->pixel[count] &= flipZero;        
                img->pixel[count+2] &= flipZero;        
            }   
            else
            {
                //flip bit
                //red
                    //check LSB and FLIP 
                //  img->pixel[count] = img->pixel[count] |= flipOne;       
                img->pixel[count+2] |= flipOne;     
            }       

            //mask--;   
            //eMsg[count] = img->pixel[count];
            //printf("count: %d\n", count);
            count = count + 3;
        }   
//      eMsg[j] = byte; 
    }

    //return encMsg = eMsg;
    //unsigned char *yes = "sucess";
    /*
    for(int a = 0; a < messageLen; a++)
    {
        printf("pixel: %c", img->pixel[a]);     
        printf("msg: %c\n", eMsg[a]);       
    //  eMsg[a] = img->pixel[a];
    }
*/

    embCount = count;   
    return embLen = embCount;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int messageLen;
    int i = 0; 
    PPMImage *img;
    int size = 0;
    FILE * fp;
    int testSize;
    fp = fopen(argv[4], "a+");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char *buff;
    buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*size +1);
    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(unsigned char)*size+1);
    fread(buff, 1, size, fp);

    fclose(fp);
//  printf("text encryption: %s\n", buff);
    testSize = strlen(buff);    
//  printf("Size of text %d\n", testSize);

    messageLen = strlen(buff); 

    img = readPPM(argv[2]);
/*
    int testing = strlen(img->pixel);
    for (int f=0;f<6;f++)
    {   
        //f2 = 1
        //f3 = 6
        printf("%c", img->pixel[f]);            
    }       
*/

//  printf("%c \n", img->pixel[2]);
//  printf("%c \n", img->pixel[5]);
    printf("\n");
//  unsigned char * encMsg;

    int encMsg = 0;         
    encMsg = embBits(img, messageLen, buff, encMsg);

//  printf("cipher msg:%s\n", img->pixel);
    printf("message length: %d\n", messageLen);
//  printf("cipher msg length: %d\n", encMsg);


    writePPM(argv[6], img->pixel, img->x, img->y);

    printf("Please press enter to complete\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: If you have done the extraction correctly then you already have the message characters in the array. Try using `%c` rather than `%x` in the `printf` to display the data as a character.

Comment: Returning address of non-static local variable doesn't seem good because the variable will vanish on returning from the function and dereferencing the address in caller will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @kaylum `dMsg[j]` will be 0 or 1 in this program and simply changiing `%x` to `%c` won't give what should be wanted.

Comment: @MikeCAT I didn't look at the code in detail because it really is unclear what it is doing. The OP wrote "giving me something such as 00110000" so I was taking that as the intention and thus prefaced my comment with "If you have done the extraction correctly..". Just trying to point the OP in the right direction with the main point being that the extracted data should already be a valid character if extracted correctly.

Comment: The image the embedding program is making is looking pretty good.  Its changing the values I want, I'm just running into issues extracting data from it.  My extractor should be able to just extract the message from the image itself.  Right now I'm popping off LSB and forming a long INT string.  I'm up for any suggestions on how to improve this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing specifically with your file and assigning each bit to a position in an array but you can print binary sequences stored in a `unsigned int`. Try using something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int arr[] = {00110110, 00111100, 10111011};
    int i = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    while(i-->0) {
        printf("%c, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit operations to gather these bits into a byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTE_LENGTH 8

#if 1
/* MSB is in data[0], LSB is in data[BYTE_LENGTH - 1] */
int arrayToChar(const int data[]) {
    int c = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BYTE_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (data[i]) c |= (1 << (BYTE_LENGTH - 1 - i));
    }
    return c;
}
#else
/* LSB is in data[0], MSB is in data[BYTE_LENGTH - 1] */
int arrayToChar(const int data[]) {
    int c = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BYTE_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (data[i]) c |= (1 << i);
    }
    return c;
}
#endif

int main(void) {
    int data[8] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int c = arrayToChar(data);
    printf("%d %c\n", c, c);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to produce one byte from 7 bits, change `BYTE_LENGTH` to 7.

If you want to deal with long sequence of bits, apply `arrayToChar` repeatedly with changing the (address of) first element to be passed.

Comment: I have a giant string which is an unsigned char *.  I'm trying to access certain ones and store the LSB of a value into something.  Once I have 8 LSB, this should form a letter.  The idea would be to convert that string to the unsigned char it represented.  However, whenever I attempt to assigned an unsigned char to any value in my unsigned char * string-  it returns blank.  I can assigned an INT to it, but not a char

Comment: basically reading a PPM p3 image-  it has values such as 16 37 29 17 etc.  I stored all of this as an unsigned char*.  I then went and flipped values such as the 37 to say 36 - creating the output 16 36 29 17.  By doing this I stored a piece of my message in the LSB of the second cause 37, making it 36.  My embedding seems to work -  but when I go to extract it those values from the LSBs, I run into an issue of not being able to store these values as anything but an INT.  If I returned out of the function I lose the scope.